# TableView with multiple cell swift

Tags: swift

I would like to call two cell. as long as chipnumber2 is not empty, I'd like to call cellnew. But " let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath.row]" line is experiencing problems.This error : fatal error: index out of range. How do I call two cell functions? This error occurs when calling Cellnew, but there is no problem when calling cell. So how do I call two cell functions in a Tableview?

```
class NewMainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MiniTabBarDelegate, NVActivityIndicatorViewable {
    var items: [Device3] = []
        var itemsNew: [Device3New] = []

        let cellId: String = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(DeviceTableViewCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return items.count
        }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

            if((chipnumber2.text?.isEmpty) != true) {

                let cellNew = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath.row]

                cellNew.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
                cellNew.badgeTextColor = .white;
                cellNew.badgeFontSize = 13;
                cellNew.badgeString = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)

                cellNew.deviceItem3New = deviceItem
                cellNew.titleNew.text = deviceItem.title
                cellNew.title1New.text = deviceItem.places
                cellNew.titlesaatNew.text = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.buttonNew.isOn = deviceItem.state

                cellNew.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)

                cellNew.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)

                return cellNew


            }

            if((chipnumber.text?.isEmpty) != true) {

            let deviceItem: Device3 = items[indexPath.row]

            cell.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
            cell.badgeTextColor = .white;
            cell.badgeFontSize = 13;
            cell.badgeString = deviceItem.time
            cell.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)

            cell.deviceItem3 = deviceItem
            cell.title.text = deviceItem.title
            cell.title1.text = deviceItem.places
            cell.titlesaat.text = deviceItem.time
            cell.button.isOn = deviceItem.state

            cell.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)


            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)

                return cell

            }
            return cell

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are using same cell identifier for both cell `let cellId: String = "cellId"
        let cellIdNew: String = "cellId"`

Comment: Don't understand why you want to call `dequeueReusableCell twice - once per call to `cellForRowAt` is enough.

Comment: Show numberOfRows method code

Comment: I update code @RajeshKumarR

Comment: Use only **one** data source array. `NumberOfRows` returns the number of items in `items` but in `cellForRowAt` you get the item from `itemsNew`. Don't do that. That's the reason for the crash.

Comment: how do I pull items + itemsNew data together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol Device with common properties

```
protocol Device {
    //common properties of both struct
    var time: String { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var places: String { get }
    var state: String { get }
}
```

Confirm to this procol in both structs and add un common properties if you need

```
struct Device3New: Device {
    var time: String
    var title: String
    var places: String
    var state: String
    //other properties
    var myVar1: String
}
struct Device3: Device {
    var time: String
    var title: String
    var places: String
    var state: String
    //other properties
    var myVar2: String
}
```

Create a common array with the type of the above protocol

Now in `numberOfRowsInSection` method check `chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty` and `chipnumber.text!.isEmpty` and append the arrays to the common array. And in `cellForRowAt` get the object from the common array.

```
class NewMainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var items: [Device3] = []
    var itemsNew: [Device3New] = []
    var joinedItems: [Device] = []
    //chipnumber, chipnumber2 textfields
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        joinedItems.removeAll()
        if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {
            joinedItems.append(contentsOf: itemsNew)
        } else if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
            joinedItems.append(contentsOf: items)
        }
        return joinedItems.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellNew = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdNew", for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

        let deviceItem: Device = joinedItems[indexPath.row]
        //common properties
        print(deviceItem.time)
        print(deviceItem.title)
        print(deviceItem.places)
        print(deviceItem.state)
        //other properties
        if let deviceItem = joinedItems[indexPath.row] as? Device3New {
            print(deviceItem.myVar1)
        } else if let deviceItem = joinedItems[indexPath.row] as? Device3 {
            print(deviceItem.myVar2)
        }
        return cellNew
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to always pull the data items, but this way it only attracts the data itemsNew. So I want to pull items + itemsNew data.

Comment: @stakabekor so you want to show itemsNew first and items next?

Comment: @stakabekor if itemsNew count is 3 and items count3, Do you want to show 6 row totally?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @stakabekor so first 3 cells will show Device3New and next 3 cells will show 
 Device3?

Comment: That way it will be accurate.

Comment: what was the description of the joinedItems: [device]? Do I have to create a class called device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193467/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-stakabekor).